# Google PlacePicker Closes After Launch with resultCode 2

Tags: android, google-maps

After clicking on add location button, the Map app opens and immediately closes again.

The result code in the onActivityResult is 2.

Log Statement:

2020-05-31 08:18:41.451 17063-17063/com.example.shushme D/MainActivity: API Client Connection Successful!

2020-05-31 08:18:42.187 17063-17063/com.example.shushme D/MainActivity: startActivityForResult i: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PICK_PLACE pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) }

2020-05-31 08:18:42.208 17063-17063/com.example.shushme D/MainActivity: startActivityForResult called

2020-05-31 08:18:42.786 17063-17063/com.example.shushme D/MainActivity: onActivityResult requestCode: 100 resultCode: 2 data: null

I changed my API key many times but still issue occurs.  I developed the SHA-1 fingerprint and added in my developer console also.
[image]

I have uploaded my code on github

GitHub Link: https://github.com/yashth/ShushMe

Please check my code and tell me what went wrong, I have already done all the steps mentioned in similar issues but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking your code, it seems that you are still using the **old Places SDK for Android** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places`. This version of Places SDK for Android has been turned off last **July 29, 2019**. There is a **new version** of the SDK `com.google.android.libraries.places:places` that is currently available and you need to [migrate](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) your implementation to the newer version to avoid issues.

Also, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place_picker_is_no_longer_available), Place Picker is no longer avaialble in the new version of Places SDK for Android. You need to use [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) instead.

You can checkout sample implementation of the new Places SDK for Android here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes Thank you that helped
Below is the link for anyone who needs ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7dYUlIKSvE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmAtMqljH9M